# Sql trigger's query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create custom id for my table in the following format

2 random alphabets - 00MaxID

for e.g: AA-001

I have tried writing a query for it but it is not working, this is my first time writing a trigger also writing a complex query such as this.

**UPDATED-2**

the following query gives me an error near "SELECT count(cus_id) INTO @ct FROM customer;"

```
CREATE
TRIGGER `id_gen` BEFORE INSERT
ON `testdb`.`customer`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    SELECT count(cus_id) INTO @ct FROM customer;

    IF @ct < 1000 THEN
        SET @cs_id = LPAD(@ct+1, 3, 0 );
    ELSE
        SET @cs_id = @ct+1;
    END IF;

    SET NEW.cus_id = CONCAT(CHAR(FLOOR(65 + RAND() * 26),FLOOR(65 + RAND() * 26)),'-',@cs_id);

END;
```

**Error**

```
 SQL query: Documentation


CREATE
    TRIGGER `id_gen` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `testdb`.`customer`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        SELECT count(cus_id) INTO @ct FROM customer
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

**Executing with Trigger Section**
[image]

Comment: I did research on triggers and I have updated my query. yet I am not able to make it work lol.

Comment: You are almost there: a) you need a "before" trigger (otherwise you cannot change values of your row) b) you cannot use `update  customer...where`, just use `set new.cus_id = ...`. In the current table, you can only manipulate the current row, which is refered to by `new.` c) There is a `THEN` missing in your `ELSEIF`. d) You are probably using `lpad` incorrectly. `lpad(string,3,0)` will give you a string with length 3, not add 3 0's. You might mean `if @ct < 1000 then set @cs_id = LPAD(@ct, 3, 0); else SET @cs_id = @ct; END IF;` (currently you would get `...LY-009, CA-10, ... GQ-99, JU-100`)

Comment: (currently you would get ...LY-009, CA-10, ... GQ-99, JU-100) I actually want these type of IDs that is why I have used such conditions. I have updated the code as u suggested. `lpad(string,3,0)` will give me a value of `length 3` , if the string itself has a `length of 2` then 0 will be added at the start of it.  **But** I am getting a syntax error on this line `SELECT count(cus_id) INTO @ct FROM customer;` any idea how to use count?

Comment: It would help if you would add the error message, but my guess is you didn't set a delimiter (as described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)), although depending on where you write your code (e.g. phpadmin), you might not need that, so it can be something different. About your ids, I was just surprised you want lenght 2 for 10..99 but length 3 for 000...009 (but that's why I used "probably", although with your last edit, I am pretty sure your `@ct+1` will give you an unexpected result (008, 009, 010, 11,12...).

Comment: I am writing this query on phpmyadmin. I have updated my posy with error message

Comment: If you do it in the trigger section, phpmyadmin will do the `create ...` part for you (so you have to remove it), if you do it in the sql section, you have to set the delimiter (add `delimiter $$` before the code, add `$$` after the last `end` and for completeness you may add `delimiter ;` after that.

Comment: Ah..! My bad. After reviewing my code, I got your point `@ct+1`. Silly me, I have updated the code too.

Comment: I have already tried with trigger section, attached SS.

Comment: @Solarflare Let it be mate, it is sad that I was not able to achieve a result. But this problem fried my brain and most likely it is the same situation for you too. But I highly appreciate all the help.Thank you.

Comment: In the screenshot, you can see that phpmyadmin automatically added code including `for each row`, which is now twice in the statement (thus the error). Your own code will start with `begin`. And a last minor thing: either use `< 999` (or `< 99` actually) instead of `<1000` or do the adding in `select count(cus_id)+1 into @ct ...`, otherwise you get the wrong id for the case when you have 99(9) rows in your table, as `lpad(999+1,3,0)` is  '100', not '1000'.

Comment: Oh God.! This works now, by removing `for each row` Thanks a bunch @Solarflare.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answered by @Solarflare.

In the screenshot, you can see that phpmyadmin automatically added code including `for each row`, which is now twice in the statement (thus the error). Your own code will start with `begin`.

```
BEGIN

    SELECT count(cus_id)+1 INTO @ct FROM customer;

    IF @ct < 1000 THEN
        SET @cs_id = LPAD(@ct, 3, 0 );
    ELSE
        SET @cs_id = @ct;
    END IF;

    SET NEW.cus_id = CONCAT(CHAR(FLOOR(65 + RAND() * 26),FLOOR(65 + RAND() * 26)),'-',@cs_id);

END;
```